# How to clear recent closed tabs on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, tabs

On my iPhone when I press the tabs button, then hold the + button, it shows all closed tabs. For some reason it isn’t showing my recent closed tabs but old ones.

How do I clear this closed recent tabs so that new recent closed tabs can start appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a bug where the list starts scrolled to the bottom. Scroll to the top to view your most recent tabs.

If you want to clear the recent tabs, you’ll have to clear your history from Safari settings.